# Inno Setup how to merge 2 different “send to” filenames?

Tags: inno-setup, sendto

In the `[Icons]` section I created 2 entries, the first will move any image to the `DropWall` folder, the second will launch my app `InsideWallpaper.exe` using the same image:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{sendto}\FFStyled (I) set InsideWallpaper image"; Filename: "{app}\DropWall";IconFilename: "{app}\FFDropWall.ico"; Tasks: sendtoicon
Name: "{sendto}\FFStyled (II) launch InsideWallpaper.exe"; Filename: "{app}\InsideWallpaper.exe";IconFilename: "{app}\FFDropWall.ico"; Tasks: sendtoicon
```

All is working fine but I would prefer to create a single `sendto` entry any Idea ?

Comment: Do you want that single entry to move the images to both folders at the same time?

Comment: actually the first entry is to a folder and the second entry is to an .exe but if you know how to merge 2 folders it could be useful thanks for the feedback !

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create a "send to" menu icon, that would deliver the file both to a folder and to an application.

All you can do it to modify the application to be able to copy the file to the folder, in addition to processing it on its own, like:

```
[Icons]
Name: "{usersendto}\FFStyled launch InsideWallpaper.exe and set InsideWallpaper image"; \
    Filename: "{app}\InsideWallpaper.exe"; Parameters: "/alsocopyto=""{app}\DropWall"""
    IconFilename: "{app}\FFDropWall.ico"; Tasks: sendtoicon
```

---

*The `{sendto}` constant has been renamed to `{usersendto}` in Inno Setup 5.6.1.*

Comment: well first the image must move to folder then the exe must starts I tried the option you kindly provided but  is not working also changing the factors order because the exe will not start

Comment: What is not working? What did you actually tried? + I also do not understand what you mean by *"also changing the factors order because the exe will not start"*.

Comment: This is the script I was able to build: Name: "{sendto}\FFStyled launch InsideWallpaper.exe and set InsideWallpaper image"; Filename: "{app}\InsideWallpaper.exe"; Parameters: "/alsocopyto=""{app}\DropWall"""; IconFilename: "{app}\FFDropWall.ico"; Tasks: sendtoicon This is what I mean for changing the factor order: Filename: "{app}\DropWall"; Parameters: "/alsocopyto=""{app}\InsideWallpaper.exe"""

Comment: You completely missed the point of my answer. No ordering of the arguments will make the job for you. You have to modify your application to implement the double-copying. Or create another application for that. A simple script (or batch file) will do too. Even simple call to `cmd.exe` can do it, but that will popup a console window, what your probably won't like.

Comment: I made a workaround                                                                           the setup will create a desktop icon shortcut pointing to the DropWall folder the user can copy and paste the image on that folder then click on the single entry SendTo menu to start the InsideWallpaper.exe any way in the tasks section I-m going to leave the option to also add the second SendTo entry